# I'd like to ask "Who in the world of RPGs uses this very strange feature?"

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I've just heard about a very strange feature for RPGs and I'd like to know who uses such a feature.

I'd like to ask:

> **Q: Where is balancing an object on your head used in RPGs?**
>
> Someone told me a story about an RPG they saw where players had to balance an object on their head to see if their character succeeded at a task.  Is this a feature of a particular game out there?

I *think* it's a reasonable question, since it could have a clear, definitive answer.  Something like:

> **A:** That's from *Fireball Legends*, an RPG published in the late 1980s.  The second edition of the game (1993) got rid of it, but the balancing-objects-on-your-head thing is still used by many *Fireball v2* gaming groups today.

Is this a reasonable kind of question?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to learn a general rule by asking about specific cases which you actually don't have a stake in. This is sort of a waste of the answerers' time. Asking about the policy you're seeking to understand will give us a chance to explain it instead of spending effort analysing a specific question you don't plan to ask. The Stack Exchange is not a place where a roundabout application of the Socratic Method will be a useful tool: just ask about the specific thing you're curious about.

Comment: *Fireball Legends* was never the same after Jonathan T. Bills sold his shares to Lamont Sweet and went back to his accounting job in Camden.

Comment: @BESW, I'm trying to ask about the general policy.  Making up an example was simply the way that seemed clearest to me at the time.

Answer (score 7):

We do these kinds of questions, with caveats.

The big cavaeat is that you need to have enough of a memory of a system to provide useful narrowing conventions. We don't have ESP so if there isn't much to go on, it's really hard for even the best RPG historians to figure out what you're looking for and find the right answer. These questions belong in the [product-identification](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-identification) tag and you can check out other question in that tag for some good examples.

However, the problem I'm having with this meta query is that the question you're referencing as bringing you to asking this question appears unrelated. You're asking about specific, group or org play level behavior, but the meta question is about a game element. It's a very different brand of question and there aren't many similarities. The question you've referenced is really broad and could potentially have hundreds of answers (and disparate ones like "my group accepts any character from any edition" to "no that's not something that's done anywhere around me" or "yes, org play group X does this!")

Comment: Worth noting this is separate from "I'm curious what games feature a mechanic for {thing}" questions, which aren't good questions. (e.g. in the past we had "which games have an arrow catching mechanic?")